# Is using 'adjust = "tukey"' in emmeans equivalent to a Tukey HSD test?

Tags: r, emmeans, tukey

I have been looking around and I am quite confused about Tukey adjustment in *emmeans*.
The [documentation of emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/emmeans.pdf) doesn't mention Tukey HSD at all, but in [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/confidence-intervals.html) it is said that "*For most contrast() results, adjust is often something else, depending on what type of contrasts are created. For example, pairwise comparisons default to adjust = "tukey", i.e., the Tukey HSD method.*".

As I understand, Tukey HSD is *essentially* a series of pairwise t-test with adjustment for type I error.
But the *emmeans* function is calculating estimated marginal means (EMMs), which I assume are not pairwise t-tests; then applying the Tukey adjustment to *emmeans* output, would not be an equivalent to Tukey HSD post hoc test.

A second related question would be what the function "tukey.emmc", also from *emmeans*, does?

[Update]
I guess my second question is, what is the difference between tukey.emmc and contrast() with 'adjust = "tukey"'?

Comment: People who bother to answer questions would like to see some evidence that you have at least read it.

Comment: I have indeed read your answer and upvoted it. Unfortunately, my reputation is still too low for my votes to be visible.

Besides that, from your answer I understood that my second question was not properly formulated, so I added an update.

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using `adjust = "tukey"` means that critical values and adjusted P values are obtained from the Studentized range distribution `qtukey()` and `ptukey()` respectively. Those are the same critical values that are used in the Tukey HSD test. But to put a very fine edge on it, the Tukey HSD method is really defined only for independent samples of equal size, which may or may not be the case for `emmeans()` results. For more details, see `? summary.emmGrid` and refer to the section on P-value adjustments.

Regarding  the second question, both `pairwise.emmc()` generates contrast coefficients for pairwise comparisons; as does `revpairwise.emmc()`. Here is a third possibility:

```
> emmeans:::tukey.emmc
function(levs, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
    if (reverse)
        revpairwise.emmc(levs, ...)
    else
        pairwise.emmc(levs, ...)
}
```

That is, `tukey.emmc()` invokes one of those pairwise-comparison methods depending on `reverse`. Thus, `contrast(..., method = "tukey", reverse = TRUE)` is equivalent to `contrast(..., method = "revpairwise")`.

Every `.emmc` function passes a default adjustment method to `contrast()`, and in the case of `pairwise.emmc()` and `tukey.emmc()`, that default is `adjust = "tukey"`. Thus, calling `contrast(..., method = "pairwise")` is the same as `contrast(..., method = "pairwise", adjust = "tukey")`. Whereas calling some other contrast function may produce different defaults. For example, `consec.emmc()` passes the `"mvt"` adjustment by default:

```
> emmeans:::consec.emmc(1:4)
  2 - 1 3 - 2 4 - 3
1    -1     0     0
2     1    -1     0
3     0     1    -1
4     0     0     1

> attributes(.Last.value)
$names
[1] "2 - 1" "3 - 2" "4 - 3"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$desc
[1] "changes between consecutive levels"

$adjust
[1] "mvt"
```

An additional comment about the Tukey adjustment: That adjustment is only appropriate for a single set of pairwise comparisons. If you specify `adjust = "tukey"` for non-pairwise comparisons or arbitrary contrasts, it will overrule you and use the `"sidak"` adjustment instead.